# PCL project in Xcode without Boost declaration

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, cmake, point-cloud-library

I found it is interesting that in my project, I forgot to include boost header but it still complied. Can anyone explain why? This is my 2 src files, then I used Cmake to make Xcode project. Thanks!

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(pcl_visualizer_viewports)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (pcl_visualizer_demo pcl_visualizer_demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries (pcl_visualizer_demo ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

pcl_visualizer_demo.cpp

```
#include <pcl/io/obj_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/vtk_lib_io.h>
#include <pcl/console/print.h>
#include <pcl/console/parse.h>
#include <pcl/console/time.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h>
void
printHelp (int,
           char **argv)
{
  PCL_ERROR ("Please enter input.obj \n", argv[0]);
}

boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> simpleVis (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr cloud)
{
    // --------------------------------------------
    // -----Open 3D viewer and add point cloud-----
    // --------------------------------------------
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
    viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
    viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> (cloud, "sample cloud");
    viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 1, "sample cloud");
    viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0);
    viewer->initCameraParameters ();
    return (viewer);
}
int
main (int argc,
      char** argv)
{
  PCL_INFO ("Display Obj file. For more information, use: %s -h\n", argv[0]);

  if (argc < 2)
  {
    printHelp (argc, argv);
    return (-1);
  }
  std::vector<int> obj_file_indices = pcl::console::parse_file_extension_argument (argc, argv, ".obj");
  if (obj_file_indices.size () != 1)
  {
    PCL_ERROR ("Need one input OBJ file.\n");
    return (-1);
  }
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr Cloud_loaded (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> ());
    pcl::io::loadOBJFile (argv[obj_file_indices[0]], *Cloud_loaded);
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer;
    viewer = simpleVis(Cloud_loaded);
   while (!viewer->wasStopped ()){
       viewer->spinOnce (100);
       boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds (100000));
}
}
```

Comment: You include PCL headers, some of them include the Boost ones in turn.

Comment: I have checked. They did not include Boost but in my CMakeCache, Cmake does point to Boost library. Is it possible that CMake scan my *.cpp file and automatically include missing library?!

Comment: [pcl/io/io_obj.h](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/include/pcl/io/obj_io.h) includes [pcl/io/file_io.h](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/include/pcl/io/file_io.h) includes [pcl/io/boost.h](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/include/pcl/io/boost.h) which is actually a wrapper aroung boost headers.

Comment: Aha, thank you! That makes sense.